# Getting Error in client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get GA data by google real time analytics api. For this i am using google api php client.
i am following below tutorial.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

I am getting error in `client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion()`. This function gives following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message
>   'config parameter "signing_key" must be set to refresh a token with
>   assertion' in
>   /Users/CFADMIN/Work/googleanalytics/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php:201

can anyone tell me why am getting this error?

Comment: anyone have solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this is that your authentication is incorrect so it hasn't generated a signing_key in the config object.

I would suggest your issue is with the  client_secret.p12 file.

Are you sure this file is populated correctly and that the path to it is correct here?

`$key_file_location = '<Replace with /path/to/generated/client_secrets.p12>';`